# Symfony 2.7 - Use entity in controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

I'm working on Symfony 2.7 and a custom bundle :

- 3 entities : Download(), Info() and User()
- 1 controller : MainController.php

I do not have "use Mycompany\Bundle\Mycustombundle\Entity\ [...]" in top of my controller, however if I test :

```
<?php

namespace Mycompany\Bundle\Mycustombundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;

class MainController extends Controller
{


    public function listAction()
    {

        [... misc. operations ...]
        [... misc. operations ...]
        [... misc. operations ...]

        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('Mycustombundle:Download');

        [... misc. operations ...]

        $new_download = new Download();
        // WORKS

        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('Mycustombundle:Info');

        [... misc. operations ...]

        $new_info = new Info();
        // WORKS

        $new_user = new User();
        // FATAL ERROR 500
        // In logs : Attempted to load class "User" from namespace "Mycompany\Bundle\Mycustombundle\Controller". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

        [... misc. operations ...]
        [... misc. operations ...]
        [... misc. operations ...]

    }

}

?>
```

How is it possible ? Is it because I work with repositories of Download and Info ?

Comment: Can you show all code (This Controller)?

Comment: Hi @ImanaliMamadiev, sorry it's way too long and there are a lot of datas to hide. By the way I edited my initial topic, maybe it's useful ?

Comment: Maybe your entities are in the controller directory?  Just guessing.  Not nearly enough information being shown.

Comment: Because here can not find you `User` class. U have to load this class from `namespace`.

Comment: are all there entities in the same directory in Mycompany\Bundle\Mycustombundle\Entity\ ?

if no, tell us where each entity is defined.

Comment: @Paolito75 if you want people to spend some time trying to help you, you should spend some time editing the damn question and adding more code of the controller stripping out what you don't want to show.

Comment: Yes, my entities are located in Mycompany\Bundle\Mycustombundle\Entity\, and my controller in Mycompany\Bundle\Mycustombundle\Controller\. I edited my initial topic with the "use" and "namespace"

Comment: Have a look at the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database

Comment: @Chris If I add "use [...]\Entity\User" it works perfectly, so i'm not stuck : I just want to understand the strange behavior

Comment: Hmmm.  My guess is that it's not actually working.  Your code is just not getting to the new statements.  I suppose it's also barely possible that you have some autoload magic going on.  Consider adding a simple testAction containing just the three new statements and see what happens.